# Best way to handle batch jobs in selenium automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests, cucumber-jvm

I am implementing a Cucumber - JVM based Selenium automation framework.

One of the workflow in the webapps i test, requires a long wait so that a batch job that is scheduled as frequently as in every 3 minutes, runs, and creates a login id, which the user can utilize, to continue with the workflow.

I am currently handling it in such a way that i execute the initial part test case first and continue with other test cases, so that the framework gets ample time to wait for the user id to be created.

After all other test cases are run the second part of the test case is run. But, before running the second part of the test case, i query the database and verify whether the id is created. If the id is created then the execution continues else, fails saying that the user id was not created.

Although this works for now, i am sure there are better ways to handle such scenarios. Have any one of you come across such a scenario? How did you handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem. You actually would like to have an execution sequence like this probably:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

But if you implement `Test 1` "correctly" it will take very long because it has to wait for the system under test to do several long running things, right?

Therefore you split `Test 1` into to parts and run the tests like this:

```
Test 1 (Part A)
Test 2
Test 3
Test 1 (Part B)
```

So that your system under test has time to finish the tasks triggered by `Test 1 (Part A)`.

As you acknowledged before, this is considered bad test design, as your test cases are no longer independent from each other. (Generally speaking no test case should rely on side effects created by another test case beforehand.)

My recommendation for that scenario would be to leave `Test 1` atomic, i.e. avoid splitting it in two parts, but still run the rest of the tests in parallel. Of course whether or ot this is feasible depends on your environment and on how you trigger the tests, but that would allow you to have a better structure of your tests plus the benefit of fast execution. So you would end up with this:

```
Test 1 starts    Test 2 starts
Test 1 waits     Test 2 finishes
Test 1 waits     Test 3 starts
Test 1 runs      Test 3 finishes
Test 1 finishes
```

Comment: Your answer assumes at least two threads. We implemented parallel execution of features so your answer is how we would do it. However with a single execution thread the "bad" way is probably best.

Comment: And if parallelism is not feasible, then...?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the start—>wait—>wait—>run approach. It might work for few tests and may not work well for hundreds of tests, as the wait time would be more. Even if we run it in parallel mode it would consume some time. What if we wait for more such time taking components in the same flow? More the components more the wait time, I guess. You may also need to consider timeout of the system, if you wait for longer time...

I feel even the first approach should be fine. No need to create multiple files for a test case. You can structure it in the same file in a way that you run first part and end it. And, after ensuring the batch processing you can start with second part of your test case(file). The first part can be run in parallel mode and after waiting time part 2 can also be executed in parallel.

Comment: I don't understand how you can possibly know if the data will be ready unless you can guarantee the intermediate tests will take an exact amount of time.